# How to check if Windows XP is activated with Python automatically?

Tags: python, windows

I need to check if Windows XP is activated automatically with Python. But **neither** of my current 2 approaches work, both of which are based on tool `msoobe.exe`

```
%systemroot%\system32\oobe\msoobe.exe /a
```

And a window will be popped to tell user if the platform is activated. The popped windows is like this:
[image]
But the problem is, I need to do that **automatically** with python.

So, I am considering in the following 2 ways:

1. If there is another parameter which can be passed to `msoobe.exe`, so that, the result will be output to a file, rather that in the popped window?
2. If I can get the text from the popped window, so that I can know the platform is activated or not.

But neither of them works for me.

For the 1st approach, I find there is **NO** such a parameter to `msoobe.exe` at all;

And for the 2nd solution, my scripts just cannot get the text. My script is like this:

```
    import win32gui, win32api, win32con
    import time 
    import subproces

    cmd = 'C:\windows\system32\oobe\msoobe.exe /a'
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    time.sleep(3)
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    con = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, 'static', None)

    print win32gui.GetWindowText(con)
```

But what I got with this script is that:

```
    ObShellMainPane
```

rather than:

```
    Windows is already activated. Click OK to exit
```

Any suggestions for me?
Is there any other approaches I can try? Or
How should I grab the test from the popped window?

Comment: For XP you can use the WMI class [`Win32_WindowsProductActivation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using either wmic.exe or the [wmi module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html). For Vista+ you can use ctypes to call [`SLIsGenuineLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much, eryksun. It works for XP. and for Vista+, I am using slmgr.vbs, a native tool.

Comment: Can you post a working solution? I don't have access to an XP system to test this.